# Deleting Google Cloud Storage object results in "Invalid argument" and "storage_class_update_time_nano" errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm unable to overwrite or remove a particular object from a Google Cloud Storage bucket that I own.

`gsutil rm`  fails with `BadRequestException: 400 Invalid argument`:

```
% gsutil stat gs://mybucket/0e133e23-6005-4711-ac2e-24b2cc95ee05.jpg
gs://mybucket/0e133e23-6005-4711-ac2e-24b2cc95ee05.jpg:
    Creation time:          Fri, 07 Aug 2015 02:03:47 GMT
    Update time:            Fri, 17 Feb 2017 04:34:43 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         46169
    Content-Type:           image/jpeg
    Metadata:               
        goog-reserved-file-mtime:1438913027
    Hash (crc32c):          UBUUbQ==
    Hash (md5):             fhU9YXjE7M6XRiT+05seeQ==
    ETag:                   CPiV3t7wlccCEAI=
    Generation:             1438913027083000
    Metageneration:         2
% gsutil rm -a gs://mybucket/0e133e23-6005-4711-ac2e-24b2cc95ee05.jpg
Removing gs://mybucket/0e133e23-6005-4711-ac2e-24b2cc95ee05.jpg#1438913027083000...
BadRequestException: 400 Invalid argument
```

The GCP Console Storage Browser fails with `Invalid argument (1 error)` and (digging deeper) `storage_class_update_time_nano must be positive`.

[image: screenshot of error after trying to delete using console]

The bucket is using the `Standard` storage class with object-level ACLs enabled (although I'm not using them, and my account is listed as an owner for the object in question). The bucket does not have a retention policy, and the default event-based hold option is disabled. It does not have any lifecycle rules.

I can remove other objects in the bucket. I'm suspecting that this is a bug on Google's side, although I haven't been able to find reports online of others experiencing the same issue (e.g. Google returns zero results for the `storage_class_update_time_nano` error message).

Comment: I suspect this is a new problem - I only started seeing this yesterday as well, and couldn't find a single relevant post anywhere about it. Then I see it again on a different project today and found your new post.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that you're seeing this problem too! I filed an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179648621.

Comment: I see on your issue that updating gsutil fixed it (and confirmed fixed for me as well), but also now deleting those same kind of problem items on GCP Console Storage Browser works as well. Thanks for reporting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved now: a `gsutil mv` command that failed in the morning of 2021-02-08 worked when I ran it again four hours later.

In the [GCP issue that I filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179648621), a Google employee confirmed that it was caused by a regression:

> I can confirm that the issue was on the GCP side and related to a new change on GCS which was performed in the beggining of February.
>
> Now I can see that the issue was rolled out and fixed.